# Count between range of date bind in gridview. LINQ to SQL Visual Basic

Tags: linq

may someone could help me on one problem in query LINQ to SQL Visual Basic.

My database  has three tables,

```
* Students(StudentID, StudentName),
* Class(ClassID, ClassDate),
* Attendance(StudentID, ClassID) which Attendance tables is the junction table between Students and Class.
```

For example:

Students

StudentsID.............StudentName

1001......................Smith

1002......................John

1003......................Bob

Class

ClassID............ClassDate

1......................1/1/2009

2......................1/3/2009

3 .....................1/7/2009

Attendance

StudentID............ClassID

1001 ...................1

1002 ...................1

1003 ...................1

1001 ...................2

1003  ...................2

1001  ...................3

1002  ...................3

1003   ...................3

I have try the query Visual Basic LINQ to SQL below to list all the student and the count number of attendance in a range of date.

```
1 Dim db = New AttendanceControllerDataContext
2
3 Dim result = From std In db.Students _
4 Select std.StudentID, _
5 std.StudentName, _
6 Attendance = std.Attendances.Count()
7
8 GridView1.DataSource = result
9 GridView1.DataBind()
```

When I try this, it gives me:

StudentID........StudentName.....Attendance

1001...............Smith.....................3

1002...............John......................2

1003...............Bob.......................3

In line 6, Attendance I want to count according to the range of date in the Class Table, For example if I selected a range of date between 1/2/2009 and 1/7/2009, then I have tried the following code:

```
 1   Dim db = AttendanceControllerDataContext

 2   Dim result = From std In db.Students, atd In db.Attendances _
 3                Where atd.studentID = std.studentID _
 4                Select std.studentID, _
 5                std.studentName, _
 6                Attendance = atd.Class.date >= 1/2/2009 _
 7                And atd.Class.date <= 1/7/2009  std.Attendances.Count()
 8   GridView1.DataSource = result
 9   GridView1.DataBind()
```

The result is:

StudentID........StudentName.....Attendance

1001...............Smith.....................2

1001...............Smith.....................2

1002...............John......................1

1003...............Bob.......................2

1003...............Bob.......................2

However, I just wanted a list that look like below only:

StudentID........StudentName.....Attendance

1001...............Smith.....................2

1002...............John......................1

1003...............Bob.......................2

How can I do this? Any suggestion? Thank in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
Attendance = std.Attendances.Count()
```

in your first code sample use

```
Attendance = std.Attendances.Where(Function(att) att.Class.ClassDate >= "1/2/2009" And att.Class.ClassDate <= "1/7/2009").Count()
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH! My Problem is solved now. This is a really useful technique. THANKS !!!!